# Azure Container in Terminated State, but Status is Running

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

We have used Azure Container Instance service to start an application which is expected to run at all times. It picks the Docker Image from ACR. The container instance got created successfully upon creation but now ACI container Instance **Status** is showing in **Running** state but when we browse Settings -> Containers, the container is shown in **Terminated** state.

Can someone please help me with the issue?

Comment: What image do you use? If it's a custom image, please provide the Dockfile.

Comment: Its one of the micro-service which has been dockerized. The logs of the service are clean and no errors what-so-ever.

Comment: You need to share the real image so that I could know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your images. If you want to run container groups with long-running processes, you could set a **restart policy** of **Always** when you create ACI, so containers in the container group always restart after they run to completion. You may need to change this to **OnFailure** or **Never** if you intend to run task-based containers. There is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-restart-policy#run-to-completion-example) that when Azure Container Instances stops a container whose restart policy is Never or OnFailure, the container's status is set to Terminated.

> When running container groups without long-running processes you may
> see repeated exits and restarts with images such as Ubuntu or Alpine.
> Connecting via EXEC will not work as the container has no process
> keeping it alive. To resolve this problem, include a start command
> like the following with your container group deployment to keep the
> container running.

Read [this common issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-continually-exits-and-restarts-no-long-running-process) for more details.

Comment: The restart policy is already set to On-Failure but the logs are clean for our service. We are currently in a fix as to what would be the reason for such a state of the Container Instance.

Comment: The Terminated state means that the application or script in the container exits with exit code 0. Containers in the container group are restarted only when the process executed in the container fails (when it terminates with a nonzero exit code). If you want to keep container status running, you can add `--command-line "tail -f /dev/null"` for linux container as the common issue in the linking of my reply.

Comment: Actually I couldn't find any error even for the microservice failure hence not really sure who caused the failure of who. Not sure if its a bug in my microservice or ACI to be frank :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it may not be the same for you. I was building my image in the `linux/arm64` platform, but Azure expects a `linux/amd64`. In my case, this started happening when I moved to an apple silicon chip.

The way I found about it can help you validate your case as well if you are still facing the issue. I created a deployment of an [Azure Container App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/container-apps/) and there the error was more explicit:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "WebhookInvalidParameterValue",
        "message": "The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Invalid value: \"<my-docker-image>": image OS/Arc must be linux/amd64 but found linux/arm64: <my-docker-image>."
    }
}
```

Hope you already got this fixed or this will help someone be unblocked